# Exception when rendering form in Umbraco using Contour v.3.0.26

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, umbraco, umbraco-contour

I upgraded to the latest version of Umbraco Contour (3.0.26). Now i get the following error:

> Error loading MacroEngine script (file: MvcRenderContourForm.cshtml,
>   Type: ''. Exception: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation
>   could destabilize the runtime.

This is thrown in MvcRenderContourForm.cshtml, line 9:

```
@Html.RenderMvcAction(action, controller, formGuid, formtoken, (umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNode)Model, (System.Dynamic.DynamicObject)Parameter);
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: What version of Umbraco is the site it's on running?

Comment: @Tim Running on Umbraco 7.1.8. I think I found a solution, though, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the oldVersion in bindingRedirect under assemblyBinding for System.Web.Mvc for some reason was set to 4.0.0.0-4.0.0.0 instead of 0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1. Fixing this set things straight.